Is there away to create Runner obejct from artifacts dir?
Normally if we use r= ansible_runner.run(...) We can get an artifacts dir with a UUID (identifier). and the r is a Runner object.
Then r.events() and r.stats() can help us to get the corresponding status of the running.
I wonder, can I somehow create the Runner object by given it the artifacts dir instead of run it. Or is there a helper function can allow me load the event by giving the artifacts root dir and the runner UUID.
